# How create a json object from POST data in Express.js?

Tags: express

i have this form:

```
form(method="POST", action="/contato")
        .row
            .col-sm-4.form-group
                label NOME
                input(type="text",name="contato[nome]").form-control
            .col-sm-4.form-group
                label TELEFONE
                input(type="text",name="contato[telefone]").form-control
        .row
            .col-sm-4.form-group.btn-group
                input(type="submit", value="Salvar").btn.btn-success
                a(href="/contato").btn.btn-primary Voltar
```

but in my route:

```
router.post('/contato', (req, res) => {
    console.log('body', req.body);
});
```

output:

> body { 'contato[nome]': 'Rafael', 'contato[telefone]': '0000' }

but i want:

```
body { contato : { nome : 'Rafael', telefone : '0000' }}
```

how do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `bodyParser` middleware might help:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
....
....
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Make sure you have both!

I'm getting this request body:

`body { contato: { nome: 'oleg', telefone: '123456' } }`